# Can females be recreated from male DNA?

Tags: human-biology, dna, reproduction

A chromosomal male is XY and a chromosomal female is XX. Now imagine if, one day, this world has only males - is it possible to "recreate" a female by using two X chromosomes from two different males?

Comment: Do you want to clone yourself with certain benefits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**
Technologically yes, but practically no, because there would be no surrogate mother available to bring the artificial XX zygote to term.

**Background**
Theoretically a cell with two male Xs can be generated, given that it is technically possible to shuttle single chromosomes between cells [(Paulis, 2011)](http://link.springer.com/protocol/10.1007%2F978-1-61779-099-7_4).

However, assuming that in your future world oocytes are available from [oocyte banks](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/838696) and sperm from [sperm banks](http://ivf.com.au/fertility-treatment/donor-program/become-a-sperm-donor) just like they are today, then the artificial combination of two Xs from male cells wouldn't be necessary in the first place, as regular [IVF](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/007279.htm) could be used.

Note that in both the chromosome transfer and IVF scenario, a female would still be necessary to implant the [zygote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygote). Until artificial wombs become available (they are [not](http://www.geneticliteracyproject.org/2015/06/12/artificial-wombs-the-coming-era-of-motherless-births/)), it is impossible to generate females without females.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Paulis, *Methods Mol Biol* (2011); **738**: 57-67](http://link.springer.com/protocol/10.1007%2F978-1-61779-099-7_4)</sub>

Comment: So, with artificial womb, we can do that? We can recreate female using two X's from men?

Comment: @JesusChrist - Given that we can transfer chromosomes between cells, I can see no reason why not.

Comment: so there's even possibility to create a female version of me using only my genetic material?

Comment: @JesusChrist - theoretically, yes. However, as far as I know it hasn't been done.

Comment: @JesusChrist, and it's probably unwise to do so. Any recessive traits on your X chromosome are, by default, winners - you're just shortening up the generational problems experienced by inbreeding. Caveat: I'm not a biologist, but that's the way I understand it to work.

Comment: @JesusChrist Your name is just godly for this question.

Comment: I would have used induced pluripotent stem cells to generate sperm and eggs. Since these eggs would likely be either X or Y, 25% of all embryos would be YY and probably nonviable. The remaining 75% would probably be ok. Similar research has [already been done in mice.](http://www.nature.com/news/rudimentary-egg-and-sperm-cells-made-from-stem-cells-1.16636)

Comment: Note that in birds and some other species with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZW_sex-determination_system the reverse is the case--males are ZZ and females are ZW.

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure how accurate that actually is.  With the other chromosomes, that would be spot on, but with the X/Y ones, you have all sorts of traits (such as male pattern baldness) that are expressed in men more often than women simply because a man only needs the one chromosome bearing the gene for the trait, which means anything that would be fatal would probably have killed the man in the first place. Caveat: I don't know of any disorders on the X that aren't expressed depending on the Y, but that doesn't mean there aren't any, and if there are, you'd be right.

Comment: @soong I think jason was trying to say that if male chromosomes were used to make a female, then both X chromosomes would be identical. If the male donor had x-linked recessive diseases, the resulting female would have those too, because both her X chromosomes would carry the defective gene.

Comment: Yes I understand that. However, x-linked recessive diseases are, too the best of my knowledge, always expressed when a man's only x chromosome has it. An example of that is male pattern baldness. Women can have it if both x chromosomes have it. So, any disease on x that is recessive, the man would already have because he has only one x.

Comment: Note that not only mammals have `XY` sexual chromosomes and your answer assumes we are talking about mammals. I assume the OP was thinking of mammals as well so it is fine but it might be worth to add a note